# Send message in GoogleChat, using library jabber-net

Tags: .net

help me please

I using labrary jabber-net to send message in google chat.
Sometines I have autorization and send message(when run application), but almost allways I can't autorization and don't send message...

using code C#:

private static string message;
        public static string _message
        {
            get { return message; }
            set { message = value; }
        }

```
    private static string emailToSend;
    public static string _emailToSend
    {
        get { return  emailToSend; }
        set { emailToSend = value; }
    }

    static JabberClient jc = new JabberClient();

    static void SendMessageToGoogleTalk(string message, string emailToSend)
    {
        jc.User = "***@gmail.com";
        jc.Server = "gmail.com";
        jc.Password = "****";
        _message = message;
        _emailToSend = emailToSend;
        jc.Connect();
        jc.OnError += client_OnError;
        jc.OnAuthenticate += client_OnAuthenticate;
        jc.Close();
    }

    static void client_OnAuthenticate(object sender)
    {
        jc.Message(emailToSend, message);
    }

    static void client_OnError(object sender, Exception exception)
    {
        isRecieveMessage = false;
    }
```

Everybody know, how I can result this problem?

Comment: Ok, just to confirm, i managed to get the code working; it authenticates with my answer below. DO NOT try to send a message to the person you authenticate with, it doesnt work but any other jabber account works to send to ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a common error basically it says that you should try username without the `@gmail.com` in the user field.

Perhaps try the following:

```
jc.User = "username";
jc.Server = "gmail.com";
```